# How the get a marginal/conditional distribution from this joint distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bayesian-network

I'm just learning about Bayesian networks and d-separation. 
Let the graph

[image]

be a model for conditional dependencies between the random variables $A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H$. From the graph, their joint distribution is given by
$$P(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
=P(a)P(b)P(c\vert b)P(d\vert c, g, h)
P(e\vert a)P(f\vert a, e)P(g\vert f)P(h\vert c,g).$$
(I write $a$ for $A=a$ and so on for convenience.)

Now, I want to infer from the model whether $A$ and $B$ are

1. independent,
2. conditionally independent given $H$.

If I applied d-separation correctly, then 1. is true and 2. is not. However, I want to confirm that by doing the computation by hand. But I'm having trouble marginalizing the joint distribution function.

For example, for 1. I want to compute

$$P(a,b)=\sum_{c,d,e,f,g,h}P(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)$$

and check whether it factors into $P(a)P(b)$.

[edit]

Okay, so for 1. I can just arrange the sums like this:

$$P(a)P(b)\sum_c P(c\vert b) \sum_e P(e\vert a)\sum_f P(f\vert a,e)\sum_g P(g\vert f)\sum_h P(h\vert c,g)\sum_d P(d\vert c, g, h).$$

The conditional probabilities sum to $1$, so $P(a,b)=P(a)P(b)$ and $a$ and $b$ are independent.

But what about 2.? I have to drop the sum over $h$, then I have

$$P(a)P(b)\sum_c P(c\vert b) \sum_e P(e\vert a)\sum_f P(f\vert a,e)\sum_g P(g\vert f) P(h\vert c,g)\sum_d P(d\vert c, g, h)$$

and I don't know how to proceed from here. In the graph, $A$ and $B$ are not d-separated because the path $(A,F,G,C,B)$ is not blocked, so they be conditionally independent given $H$. How can I confirm this by showing that $P(a,b\vert h) \neq P(a\vert h)P(b\vert h)$ by means of the given joint probability function?

Comment: Simply sum the RHS of $$P(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
=P(a)P(b)P(c\vert b)P(d\vert c, g, h)
P(e\vert a)P(f\vert a, e)P(g\vert f)P(h\vert c,g)$$ successively (and in this order) over $d$ then over $h$ then over $g$ then over $f$ and finally over $e$ and $c$.

Comment: Thank you. This solves 1. However, I still don't understand how to compute the marginal distribution in the case where I cannot order the sums in a way that makes them neatly go away. (Edited my question accordingly.)